# Correct way to upgrade to Win 10 from Win 8 downgraded to Win 7?

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade, license

Got a new laptop with Win 8 license preset in BIOS with Win 7 actually installed. Would like to upgrade to Win 10. Can I upgrade directly from existing Win 7 installation or should I reinstall Win 8 first and then upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade from windows 7 directly. It'll just look at the valid (it is valid right?) windows 7 licence then try to upgrade as per normal. There's little point, to me, to a 2 stage upgrade.

Just to note that in my experience, the update to windows 10 has failed on 3 of 3 systems I've tried it on, so you may need to delete the download folder, run the update tool, or use a dvd to upgrade. Its not due to whatever version of windows you have currently.

Comment: Confirmed, works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can upgrade from Win7 directly. I'd suggest to use the MediaCreationTool. With this tool you can start the update on your workstation and - if you want to - create an ISO to later run on another PC. It's a bit faster than Windows Update I think (even though it's pretty much the same)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10